# Do I need a physical iPhone to compile and distribute IOS apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, qt

I have a simple app (in Qt/C++) which compiles and runs great in the iphone simulator on my Mac.  When I try to compile it (kit) for the IOS (non-simulator) I get a warning that my kit settings are incomplete.

**Qt**: In the Kit settings for IOS Qt insists on selecting a device - which I don't have.  So the kit is incomplete, and I get compilation errors.  (and Kit has a warning sign).
**Apple**: During compile I get an error that relates to missing IOS App Development Profile...but I plan to distribute so why does it want a development profile?  I have a IOS App distribution profile.

I was hoping to build and test my app using simulator only, then distribute in apple store.

1. Do I need a physical iphone so Qt Creator Kit is happy?
2. Do I need a physical iphone so Apple can create and IOS App Development platform which is a prerequisite to compilation?

Comment: All you need is a Mac OS and Xcode, you don't need a physical iphone. Just make sure you have everything else set up correctly.

Comment: Can you comment on why I'm getting an error that an IOS App Development Profile is needed?  Shouldn't I only need a IOS App Distribution Profile?  (Or do you need Dev profile to compile

Comment: I'd suggest to just try and build the app, it should generate a `.xcodeproj` file, even when it complains about errors, then open it in xcode. That's how I usually do it. If however it doesn't even make the `.xcodeproj` then I can't help much.

Comment: Same error building from within xcode.  I

Comment: No, such device is not required, but it is recommended. Some things can be tested only on real device.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in this situation, it seems that XCode needs a development profile to compile (regardless of whether or not you plan to distribute) for anything other than a simulator.  Then, it needs a distribution profile if you want to distribute the app.

Since a development profile must include the Universal Device ID for at least one device, you need to add at least one device.  (Or you need to get the UDID of a real apple device to create one).  Once you have the development profile you can compile and distribute the app.

I could not find any way around this.  (Note that if you are compiling for the simulator it will compile without the profile, BUT, the simulator UDID is refused as a valid device in the apple store connect)

Once XCode is happy then Qt is happy